# How to extract data from a particular area in a PDF file

Tags: php, pdf, extract, tcpdf, pdftotext

See this [pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EmjPV4bodxvaQqkdu_W_Z7on9h-qtPNQ/view?usp=sharing)

I want this data from this pdf

```
<?php
$data = array(
 "CertificateID" => "91815380284",
 "BeneficiaryName"=>"Kavita",
 "Gender" => "Female",
 "IDVerified" => "Aadhaar # XXXXXXXX3661",
 "BeneficiaryReferenceID" => "34684952644017",
 "VaccinationStatus" => "Fully Vaccinated (2 Doses)"
);
?>
```

Comment: Uhhh is that someones personal information?

Comment: There's many PDF to text readers built in PHP. Go out there and try one.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The actual task you want to perform is not suited for PHP.

It is better to use external program, like pdftotext https://www.xpdfreader.com/pdftotext-man.html.

The main problem with PDF is that they are not simply text file, but a binary.

You can invoke the pdftotext with `shell_exec` command and get the output in PHP for further processing.

After you have the parsed PDF data in PHP just use regexes to get the line you want.

This should be the framework to work with for PDFs like this one.

Other ways is to use more advanced techniques - python has a lot of good
libraries for this job:

- https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- https://tabula.technology/
- and more

Answer (score 0):

You nominated pdftotext as your application and your sample is regular enough to use command line cropping so for a text data output file like

[image]

you can use

```
pdftotext -nopgbrk -marginl 200 -margint 150 -marginb 500 -layout "certificate (9).pdf" test.txt
```

However since your code  does not show a conversion method you will need to adapt the output lines (either ignoring age or extracting two or more chunks) to get your desired

```
 "CertificateID" => "91815380284",
 "BeneficiaryName"=>"Kavita",
 "Gender" => "Female",
 "IDVerified" => "Aadhaar # XXXXXXXX3661",
 "BeneficiaryReferenceID" => "34684952644017",
 "VaccinationStatus" => "Fully Vaccinated (2 Doses)"
```